# Converting binary data to bytes in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, bitarray

we have a text file containing binary values.
say, we have a file "file.txt",it contains binary datat, say **11001010**
the size of this file is *8 bytes*.
but we want these *8 bytes* to be read as bits i.e. *8 bits* and thus make 8 bits into 1 byte. How can we do it?
we just know the procedure:
1. take a buffer and read individual value into buffer
2.if the buffer value reaches 8,make those 8 bits into a byte and write to a file.

thanks in advance.

Comment: we dont know where to start. we also tried to name it as "file.bin",but no use

Comment: @Henk, he is saying the file contains 0s and 1s.

Comment: @RoyDictus : Yeah, more like `'0'` and `'1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code reads such a text file as you describe. If the file contains a number of binary digits that is not divisible by 8, the extraneous digits are discarded.

```
using (var fileToReadFrom = File.OpenRead(@"..."))
using (var fileToWriteTo = File.OpenWrite(@"..."))
{
    var s = "";
    while (true)
    {
        var byteRead = fileToReadFrom.ReadByte();
        if (byteRead == -1)
            break;
        if (byteRead != '0' && byteRead != '1')
        {
            // If you want to throw on unexpected characters...
            throw new InvalidDataException(@"The file contains a character other than 0 or 1.");
            // If you want to ignore all characters except binary digits...
            continue;
        }
        s += (char) byteRead;
        if (s.Length == 8)
        {
            fileToWriteTo.WriteByte(Convert.ToByte(s, 2));
            s = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Given a string, I suspect you want [`Convert.ToByte(text, 2);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k.aspx)

For more than a single byte, I don't think there's anything built in to convert a long string to a byte array like this, but you could use `Substring` repeatedly if you want.

Comment: @Timwi: Because I haven't had enough coffee. Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case we are talking about bytes and not chars:

```
        byte output;
        using (var inFile = File.OpenRead("source"))
        {
            int offset = 0;
            var data = new byte[8];
            while (inFile.Read(data, offset, 8) == 8)
            {
                output = (byte)(data[0] << 7);
                output += (byte)(data[1] << 6);
                output += (byte)(data[2] << 5);
                output += (byte)(data[3] << 4);
                output += (byte)(data[4] << 3);
                output += (byte)(data[5] << 2);
                output += (byte)(data[6] << 1);
                output += (byte)data[7];

                offset += 8;

                // write your output byte
            }
        }
```